# How add columns with variable and different names in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe in pandas, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})
```

I want to add new columns dynamically with names depending on the current iteration.
I tried

```
for k in range(2):
   column_name = 'new_column_' + str(k)
   df = df.assign(column_name=[0,0,0])
```

As output, I expected

```
   A  B  C  new_column_0  new_column_1
0  1  4  7             0             0
1  2  5  8             0             0
2  3  6  9             0             0
```

Unfortunately, only one column is created with the name 'column_name'.

How can I dynamically add columns with names determined by variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cau use [`pandas.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) like below.

```
df = df.assign(**{f'new_column_{k}' : 0 for k in range(2)})
print(df)
```

---

```
   A  B  C  new_column_0  new_column_1
0  1  4  7             0             0
1  2  5  8             0             0
2  3  6  9             0             0
```